# webapi 3D spatialization: how to apply distance delay

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, webapi

**Goal**

I'm trying to build a site with spatialized audio.

**Measure**

I'm using WebAudioAPI's `PannerNode`.

My Audiopipeline looks like:  `audioTrack → PannerNode → audioContext.destination`

**Expected**

I thought a PannerNode would do everything to create 3D audio experience.

**Problem**

I feel like there is no sound delay between the left and right speaker. The kind of sound delay that occurs because both ears have a spatial distance to each other.

**Question**

1. Is my feeling wrong, and there is actually a delay between left and right speaker? (maybe my settings are wrong/ not optimal.)
2. Is there a convenient way of implementing the sound delay or do I need to go through `track -> PannerNode -> SplitAudioInChannels -> ApplySoundDelayPerChannel -> Output` manually?

**Code**

I'm basically using the code from [mozilla's tutorial here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Web_audio_spatialization_basics).

PannerNode is setup as follows:

```
var panner = new PannerNode(audioCtx, {
    panningModel: 'HRTF',
    distanceModel: 'linear',
    positionX: audioSource.x,
    positionY: audioSource.y,
    positionZ: 0,
    orientationX: 0.0,
    orientationY: 0.0,
    orientationZ: 0.0, // -1 = face out of the screen
    refDistance: 1,
    maxDistance: 400,
    rolloffFactor: 10,
    coneInnerAngle: 360, //60,
    coneOuterAngle: 360, //90,
    coneOuterGain: 0.3
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

To hear the spatialization effect, you need to change your orientation and/or position.  To see if your panner is doing something, I'd look at [Canopy](https://hoch.github.io/canopy) to see the left and right channels from the panner.  Adjusting the position and/or orientation should show there is a delay difference between the left and right channels.

Here's a short example for use in Canopy to show that the left and right channels have different delays.  Paste this into the code window and press the triangle on the left to render.  You'll see waveforms at the top, one for each channel.  If you zoom in, you can see the first channel doesn't start at the same time as the second.

```
// @channels 2
// @duration 1.0
// @sampleRate 44100

let osc = new OscillatorNode(context, {type: "square");


let p = new PannerNode(context);
p.panningModel = "HRTF";
p.positionX.value = 10;
p.positionY.value = 10;
p.positionZ.value = 10;

osc.connect(p).connect(context.destination);

osc.start();
```

Comment: That means, sound delay should actually been already implemented by WebAudioAPI. I'm not sure how Canopy is supposed to work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a small canopy snippet that illustrates that the two channels have different delays.